# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON') - Discord.js slash commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, slash

I tried making slash commands today on Discord.js, but my console threw some errors that it cannot read the property `toJSON` what can be the possible solution to it?

Here are my errors:

```js
~/.../stuff/hazy $ node hazy.js
/storage/emulated/0/stuff/hazy/hazy.js:163
  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/storage/emulated/0/stuff/hazy/hazy.js:163:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Here is my code:

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Place your client and guild ids here
const clientId = '913559840780091453';
const guildId = '912552644462121050';

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: `command.data.toJSON` does not exist on this object. try `JSON.stringify(command.data)` instead.

Comment: do you want me to write `commands.push(command.data.JSON.stringify(command.data);`?

Comment: or `commands.push(JSON.stringify(command.data));`?

Comment: well i will try both in this case lol

Comment: thanks for helping me, it worked, but it still have an error saying `DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body`

Comment: @Vincent the error indicates that `command.data` is undefined. If `toJSON` did not exist on that object the error would be "... is not a function". @coco bar your loop ran into a `command` object which does not have a `data` property. Check all of your command files & objects and ensure they each have one.

Comment: @Elitezen Thanks for correcting me, you're right! I mus have misread the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
```

with

```
commands.push(JSON.stringify(command.data));
```

Thanks to Vincent for helping!

Answer (score 1):

From the error you are receiving, I can see that the `data` property apparently doesn't exist on the `command` object. Have you defined/exported it in the respective command file?

Try logging the `command.data` object to see if anything pops up. That's probably the error.